# How to Create DateTime object from 2014-09-02T08:54:03Z

Tags: php, datetime

How to Create DateTime object from `2014-09-02T08:54:03Z` ?
but with `2014-09-02 08:54:03` works just fine

```
$str = '2014-09-02T08:54:03Z';
$date_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $str);
var_dump($date_time);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datetime using predefined [`ISO8601` format](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). Try this:

```
$date_time = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, $str);
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
DateTime implements DateTimeInterface {
    //...
    const string ISO8601 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO" ;
    //...
}
```

> DateTime::ISO8601
>
> DATE_ISO8601
>
> ISO-8601 (example: 2005-08-15T15:52:01+0000)